# Creating copy of object

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, copy-constructor

I would like to create a copy of current object and store it inside an array , where, later on i can access it.

I have  a class

```
class Purpose{
public:
  Purpose(){
    max          = 5;
    elements     = 0;
    obj_elements = 0;
    arr          = new int[max];
  }
  Purpose( const Purpose &a){
    max          = a.max;
    elements     = a.elements;
    obj_elements = a.obj_elements;
    arr          = new int[elements]
    for( int i = 0; i < elements; i++ ){
       arr[i] = a.arr[i]
    }
  }

 Add(){
   Purpose *tmp = new Purpose(*this);
   arr_two[ obj_elements++ ] = tmp;
 }
private:
  int max;
  int elements;
  int obj_elements;
  int *arr;
  Purpose *arr_two[2];
}
```

I am adding ints inside the `arr` array.
The Add() method creates the copy of current object and store it inside `arr_two` array but when i want to print the elements of copied object , it throws seg fault.

```
void Purpose::Print_It(){

        cout << arr_two[ obj_elements - 1 ] -> max << endl;
        cout << arr_two[ obj_elements - 1 ] -> elements << endl;
        cout << arr_two[ obj_elements - 1 ] -> obj_elements << endl;
        for( int i = 0; i < arr_two[ obj_elements - 1 ] -> elements ; i++){
         cout << arr_two[ obj_elements - 1 ] -> arr[i] << endl

        }

    }
```

The printing of the elements of arr throws seg fault. The others attributes are printed without problem.

What causes the program to crash/seg fault while printing values of the array? When i print the values of the array inside `Add()` method it works.

Comment: Every aspect of this code is absolutely terribly ill-advised. Is there any reason for any of this, and why you can't just use `std::vector<int>` and be done with it?

Comment: i would like to practise without using vector.

Comment: If you are just practicing, then that should include practicing doing your own debugging. :)

Comment: I have a new rule whereby I won't help people who are deliberately crippling themselves and their programs by insisting on using the worst solution possible, then wondering why it doesn't work. Good luck.

Comment: People are not always crippling themselves on purpose. In school , we have tasks where we are not allowed to use vector = create somethign without using STL. Thats why i am trying to implement things using array too.

Comment: @trolkura  *create somethign without using STL.* -- Then you should have gotten instructions from a competent C++ instructor on how to proceed in doing this, with requisite examples, and not just throw an assignment at you without this guidance.  Otherwise it comes down to someone on SO practically wasting time teaching how to properly create classes that have members that point to dynamically allocated memory.  Contrary to what you may believe, this ultimately is *not* a trivial thing to get correct.

Answer (score 1):

You call the new[] operator with a size of 0 (elements is initialized to 0)?

From [cplusplus website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/) on the new[] operator in regards to the size_t parameter:

> If this argument is zero, the function still returns a distinct non-null pointer on success (although dereferencing this pointer leads to undefined behavior).